# Catch all touch events in UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ipad

I want a timer to reset every time the user is touching the screen in my app (So i know that user are still using the device). I have implemented touchBegan in my ViewController.

The problem is if i have a UITableView in my ViewController and user touches the UITableView the function touchBegan is never being called. Reason is that the tableView dosn't pass along the touch event.

What i've understand you can either subclass UITableView to pass it to it's superview or add a transparent UIView on top that only catches touch event and passing them. Problem with subclassing is that i need to do it on all classes that catches touch event.

Is there a better solution? If not how do you pass the event to it's superview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could subclass `UIWindow` or `UIApplication` and override `sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and take action from there.

e.x. (if you override `UIApplication`)

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   if (event.type == UIEventTypeTouches)
      [(YourApplicationDelegate *)self.delegate wakeUp:event];
   [super sendEvent:event];
}
```

This may be a bit invasive for what you're trying to do.  Would love to see some other ideas.

Comment: It actually works like the way i want it, the problem is that i dont seem to find a way to detect if it is touchBegan. Atm if i scroll in the scroll view wakeUp is being called 20-30 times.

Comment: Answer to my own Question: UITouch *touch = [event allTouches].anyObject;
        if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {

Comment: This no longer works for me in iOS7.  See my answer below for how I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions no longer work with iOS 7.

If you just want to know when the screen was touched, put the following in your ViewController.m file...

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer 
                                                shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer
{
  if (otherGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
  {
    // yes, it was touched!
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should subclass `UIScrollView` (or `UITableView` - that extends from `UIScrollView`) just to handle touch events, as there are some other ways to accomplish what you might be looking for in a cleaner way.

When using `UISCrollView` or `MKMapView` (which does not pass along the touch events as well) I generally use an UIGestureRecognizer to catch the specific touch events that I am looking for.

For some specific cases, as handling the touch of a `UITableView` in the screen just to dismiss a keyboard, I set the `UIScrollView` property `userInteractionEnable` to `NO` at the `textViewDidBeginEditing` `UITextView` delegate method, and then set `userInteractionEnable` to `YES` at `textViewDidEndEditing`. Doing this will enable me to catch the `touchesBegan` without subclassing anything.