# iOS How do I tell when a user is interacting with the app?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

Goal:
I need to be able to tell when a user is interacting with an `iPhone` app.
After 5 minutes, I will auto `logout` the user, but I don't want to do that if the user is interacting with the app.

I have read about `shouldReceiveTouch:`, but that it will be called if a user touches something. I could put login in there to reset the 5 minute timer.

How do I make it so that if any `view` on any screen is touched, the 5 minute timer starts over?

Is it possible to do this without implementing `shouldReceiveTouch:` everywhere?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you consider the fact the app while its in foreground as if the user is interacting? if yes you can use applicationDidEnterBackground and count time to logout user

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 3 approaches:

- **(1)** The best one I think is suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774498/catch-all-touch-events-in-uiview). Basically you would override `-sendEvent:` on `UIApplication`. But someone mentions this might not work anymore since iOS 7 - YMMV.
- **(2)** Another, less clean solution would be to use [method swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/). You could replace a method on UIView for your own implementation, e.g. `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` or `-hitTest:withEvent:`.
- **(3)** If your app doesn't use any 3rd party view controller, you could create a custom base class of UIViewController and make all your view controllers (except login view controller and anything shown before) inherit from this base class. This view controller would have a gesture recognizer or perhaps override a method like `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` or `-hitTest:withEvent:`.

For all approaches you would probably use a singleton to keep track of the last touched moment. Perhaps the singleton would use a countdown timer. The singleton could have [a multicast delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24253640/250164) or use `NSNotificationCenter` to inform other view controllers that the timer has run out.

---

***P.S.**: I should note that you should consider method swizzling carefully. If some other project or library swizzles the same method, you will never know for sure which implementation is used for the swizzled method.*

Comment: I don't know why someone downVote without at least a comment on what wrong !

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my answer though. I could even create an example project. I wish people would tell why they downvote as well.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think approach **(1)** and **(3)** are the best. But **(3)** would not work if you show 3rd party view controllers in your app, in that case **(2)** might be better. Option **(1)** might not work anymore since iOS 7.

Comment: If you need a code example for option **(2)**, let me know and I'll add one tomorrow.